# Python mocking class instantiation and accessing private member variable

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I want to test a method inside a class which updates the value of a member variable. However class takes constructor arguments which are not required in the method to test.

```
class SimpleClass(Database):
    count = None

    def intoTwo(self, v):
        self.count = 2*v
```

Now I am testing method as follows

```
import unittest
import mock

class TestSimpleClass(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock.patch('SimpleClass', autospec=True)
    def test_intoTwo(self, mock_simpleclass):
        mock_instance = mock_simpleclass.return_value
        mock_instance.intoTwo(2)
        self.assertEqual(mock_instance.count,4)
```

I am getting following error:

```
<NonCallableMagicMock name='SimpleClass().count' id='139921148836112'>
```

Please suggest the solution for this. I count not find something relevant in other posts or blogs.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. You have an instance of MagicMock and you call a method on it. Nothing here ever references the original class.

Comment: mock_instance.count in assert?

Comment: What? That's just a mock value itself, as the response shows. Why do you think it would be 4?

Comment: So mock_instance.intTwo wont call actual intoTwo function? intoTwo function sets the value of count inside class.